# What type of dependencies we need in Angular 4 in order to incorporate Bootstrap 3?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-cli

I am coding a simple Angular 4 application with Bootstrap 3. For some reasons, my navigation bar (navbar-default) is not collapsing. I have added the bootstrap module in `angular.cli` files along with jQuery.

Code is as follows :

```
 <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div><!-- nav-collapse -->
    </nav>
```

This is what I have tried:

1. imported bootstrap3 module and saved it with cli
2. imported jQuery module using npm
3. added jQuery  and `bootstrap.min.js` in angular cli json file in scripts
4. after importing the above I can see the jQuery in the index.html but I can't see `bootstrap.min.js` file in the header of my index

   [Added Dependencies in angular-cli.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNfWn.png)
   [Downloaded and installed bootstrap3 module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPKPw.png)
   [Downloaded and installed jQuery module for Angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv7QF.png)
   [Although, I do not see any jQuery or bootstrap.js installed on my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik8eo.png)

Do I need anything else besides those two? I have done a little bit of research and learned in bootstrap 4 we have different modules for every component of bootstrap for example collapse, accordion, and modals etc. etc.

I believe there could be a simple solution to this problem. I definitely need a different pair of eyes on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the Bootstrap CSS as well: insert this in your index.html and it will work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

It is in the [install guide](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) but easy to miss :)

Comment: CSS was there. I was missing bootstrap.min.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Execute  `npm install bootstrap@3 jquery --save`

After this  Add file paths to the styles and scripts array in file .angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

I guess you missed to add bootstrap.min.css in styles array

Comment: Thanks Vikas. I missed the bootstrap.min.js part. Working fine now.

Comment: glad I could help :)

Comment: @ Hemant Kumar Can you make it as a correct answer if it resolved your issue?